# Set the background image of a div using the url of the first image in another using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this HTML:

```
<article>
    <div class="look">
    </div>

    <div class="read">
        <img src="http://mysite.com/some-image.jpg">
    </div>
</article>

<article>
    <div class="look">
    </div>

    <div class="read">
        <img src="http://mysite.com/another-image.jpg">
    </div>
</article>

<article>
    <div class="look">
    </div>

    <div class="read">
        <img src="http://mysite.com/yet-another-image.jpg">
    </div>
</article>
```

For each instance of `<article>` I'm trying to use jQuery to set the background image of `<div class="look">` using the first image within `<div class="read">`. So far, this (below) seems to work, but it sets the same image (in the last instance of `<article>`) for all instances of `<div class="look">`. I need each instance of `<div class="look">` to be set from each instance of `<div class="read">`. Here's my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.read').find('img').each(function(n, image){
        var image = $(image);
        var thisurl = $(this).attr('src');
        $('.look').css('background-image', 'url(' + thisurl + ')');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.look').css('background-image', function(){ 
        return 'url(' + $(this).next().find('img').attr("src") + ')';
    })
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5GkK6/)** (hiding the img elements to make seeing the background easier)